# Error While installing perl Packages in Freebsd?

Tags: perl, package, freebsd, cpan

I am getting this error while installing any perl module in a freebsd server when I googled it I Found that cpan is broken then how to update cpan without using ports want to use only pkg..

```
cpan JSON
Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 04 Oct 2016 19:17:02 GMT
Going to read '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz'
DONE
Going to read '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz'
Warning: Your /root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz does not contain a Line-Count header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
Warning: Your /root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz does not contain a Last-Updated header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
DONE
Going to read '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/03modlist.data.gz'
Can't locate object method "data" via package "CPAN::Modulelist" (perhaps you forgot to load "CPAN::Modulelist"?) at (eval 28) line 1.
 at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.14.2/CPAN/Index.pm line 524
    CPAN::Index::rd_modlist('CPAN::Index', '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/03modlist.data.gz') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.14.2/CPAN/Index.pm line 85
    CPAN::Index::reload('CPAN::Index') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.14.2/CPAN.pm line 975
    CPAN::exists('CPAN=HASH(0x8021b7570)', 'CPAN::Module', 'JSON') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.14.2/CPAN/Shell.pm line 1255
    CPAN::Shell::expandany('CPAN::Shell', 'JSON') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.14.2/CPAN/Shell.pm line 1680
    CPAN::Shell::rematein('CPAN::Shell', 'install', 'JSON') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.14.2/CPAN/Shell.pm line 1976
    CPAN::Shell::__ANON__('CPAN::Shell', 'JSON') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.14.2/App/Cpan.pm line 459
    App::Cpan::__ANON__('JSON') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.14.2/App/Cpan.pm line 468
    App::Cpan::_default('ARRAY(0x801060798)', 'HASH(0x8021c1ab0)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.14.2/App/Cpan.pm line 386
    App::Cpan::run('App::Cpan', 'JSON') called at /usr/local/bin/cpan line 11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just tried this

```
mv /root/.cpan /root/.cpanbackup
```

and used CPAN again It is working fine.

Comment: Sorry, the error message could be a little bit more clear. ISTR this happens when a proxy error message in HTML or some other unexpected or incomplete junk ends up in the `0*.txt.gz` files, and then the CPAN client gets confused about the contents. Starting over cleanly was the correct thing to do.